# Can I visit Schengen countries after using all days allowed by a national D visa?

Tags: schengen

I have a Schengen D visa valid for 1 year with possibility to stay 183 days. Can I enter other Schengen countries after using 183 days allowed by national visa but before the expiration of the visa.

Comment: After the national visa is expired, you have exactly the same rights to enter Schengen countries, as if you had not had the national visa. The days spent in the issuing country are not relevant, when counting any visa-free visit allowance. If I conclude correctly from your profile, that you are an Ukrainian, you will of course need a regular short-term visitor visa to enter the Schengen area again after the expiration of your Estonian national visa.

Comment: but as I understand visa is not expire when 183 days are used. So I can use it until the valid until period

Comment: Then you must explain more clearly what you do have and do not have. Currently, your question sounds as if you have a national visa valid for 183 days (which is rather odd).

Comment: Sorry i was not clear I think. I have D visa valid for 1 year with possibility to stay 183 days. and i wanted to ask if I can enter other Schengen countries after using 183 days allowed by national visa but before the expiration of the visa

Comment: This depends upon your nationality. If you are a visa national, then no you cannot.